# Running Stack on NixOS Causes Missing C Compiler Error

Tags: haskell-stack, nixos

Running `stack build` and even `stack --nix build` on a NixOS build yields the following:

```
Linking /run/user/1000/stack7176/old-time-1.1.0.3/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nix/Cabal-1.22.5.0/setup/setup ...
Configuring old-time-1.1.0.3...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler, --with-gcc
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/run/user/1000/stack7176/old-time-1.1.0.3':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

I have installed `gcc` and `clang` on my system and verified that, i.e., `gcc` is indeed on my path. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What NixOS channel are you on?

Comment: @Chris: `nixos-unstable`

Comment: I don't know what's wrong here, but for what it's worth, you shouldn't have to install `gcc` and `clang`; that's the whole point of the Nix integration, Stack ought to be starting its own nix-shell environment with everything it needs.

Comment: Can you post a minimal stack file to reproduce this?